# Javascript: splice strange behavior

Tags: javascript

I'm running a splice on an array like this, where the array has 5 elements:

```
array.splice(3, 0, newObj);
```

The splice doesn't work and I still have 5 elements.

When I debug it in Chrome with console.log I see an array of six objects, but when I open the array I see five elements (see pic below). What does this mean?

[image]

Comment: Very likely a display problem/error. `splice()` works correctly, it inserts a new element at index 3.

Comment: Probably the last is null so Chrome isn't showing it?

Comment: The console does some caching of output.

Comment: When do you `console.log` the object? Chrome only evaluates the object when you click on the arrow. Is it possible the object is modified in between?

Comment: you should no rely on console.log to display this kind of information, you should use breakpoints to check the value at time T.

Comment: @RGraham yes I modify the object after console.log, I incorrectly thought that the object on the console wouldn't change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're inserting a new object into that array -> `newObj`

For example, if you run this in `Chrome console`, works fine :

```
function aHandler (){
  var a =  [{1:1},{1:2},{1:3},{1:4},{1:5}];
  a.splice(3,0,{1:20});
  console.log(a);
};  aHandler();
```

Even if you insert `null` or `undefined` `console.log` should show you the right object.

So, maybe you modify the object somewhere between `splice` and `console.log`

Comment: does that mean I cannot rely on console.log, just in case I modify the object **after** it is shown on the console?